# create a stellar application without installing stellar core in local system

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-sdk

I want to create a stellar application which will have these functionality

- Account creation
- XLM Balance checking
- Doing Transaction
- XLM Receive notification

I have read stellar documenation https://www.stellar.org/developers/

Based on that i have generated keys:

```
var pair = StellarSdk.Keypair.random();
pair.secret();
pair.publicKey();
```

And to create account i hit this url in browser

https://friendbot.stellar.org?addr=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

**How can i create a account in livenet without installing stellar-core**

I did't find any livenet endpoint in stellar docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create accounts you create a transaction containing a `createAccount` operation.

https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#create-account

Friendbot is only there to give you an initial sum of testnet XLMs. Nothing else.

Comment: I have used this code to create account :` StellarSdk.Keypair.random(); pair.secret(); pair.publicKey();` . If i make transaction without hitting `https://friendbot.stellar.org?addr=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` url  gives a 404 and Resource Missing exception

Comment: Keypair.random() only *generates* a keypair for you.

To be able to use the account, it has to be registered on the ledger, and that's what the `createAccount` operation does.

Comment: https://www.stellar.org/developers/js-stellar-base/reference/base-examples.html#creating-an-account

Comment: That's right. An account can't exist without a minimum balance. And you can't create that minimum balance out of thin air, someone has to give it to you by way of a CreateAccount operation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to directly access Stellar Core, if you just want the above functionalities.

Use the livenet Horizon endpoint would be sufficient:

```
https://horizon.stellar.org/
```

For pre-built UI version, use the Laboratory: https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/

---

To see JS example code for your target actions, refer to https://www.stellar.org/developers/js-stellar-base/reference/base-examples.html

NOTE: `StellarSdk.Network.useTestNetwork();` is for TESTNET, so you need to change it to something like `StellarSdk.Network.usePublicNetwork();`

p.s. I'd recommend trying first with testnet and observe if your calls match with the expected behaviour first.